# devolver valor de un combobox en php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un combobox o select para los registros de una tabla, en mi tabla tengo  2 registros insertados ya:

```
<form>
       <h1>Unidad</h1>
        <select id="unidad" name="unidad" >
            <option value="unidad1">Unidad I</option>
            <option value="unidad2">Unidad II</option>
            <option value="unidad3">Unidad III</option>
            <option value="unidad4">Unidad IV</option>
            <option value="unidad5">Unidad V</option>

        </select>
</form>
```

Cuando elijo por ejemplo unidad I, se me pone en los dos registros y quisiera saber como hacer para que el valor no se ponga en los dos registros, por ejemplo que en el registro uno elija unidad I y en el segundo pueda poner unidad III sin que se ponga en el los dos registros el mismo valor que seleccione, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No sabemos cómo es la consulta que pone esta información en la tabla. Por favor, añade ese fragmento de código (como texto, ojalá)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <h1>Unidad</h1>
    <select id="unidad[]" name="unidad[]" multiple >
        <option value="unidad1">Unidad I</option>
        <option value="unidad2">Unidad II</option>
        <option value="unidad3">Unidad III</option>
        <option value="unidad4">Unidad IV</option>
        <option value="unidad5">Unidad V</option>

    </select>
```

Debes agregar esto en tu código, para permitir selección múltiple, y que esos valores múltiples se graben en un arreglo.

Del otro lado recibes los valores, de esta manera.

```
$unidades=$_POST["unidad"];
foreach ($unidades as $selectedOption)
echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta del OP

Comment: Disculpa, pero no veo como es que no responde su pregunta, segun entiendo el quiere seleccionar 2 opciones y que le lleguen esos mismo 2 valores, por el codigo que muestra su problema es primero que no puso la opcion Multiple en el select y segundo que la variable debe ser un arreglo. Si no entendí bien la pregunta entonces me disculpo. Saludos.